# How do I use try catch to avoid throws exception?

Tags: java

I was trying to create a set data structure and populate it with all the words from the dictionary file, inside the constructor of my class, but kept on getting errors on the FileNotFoundException part:

```
public class CaesarCipher {

public CaesarCipher()  {
    try {
    File dict = new File("dictionary/google10000.txt");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File does not exist, please try again: ");
    }
}
public String decode(String s) {
    String [] word = s.split("");
    Set<String> dict = new HashSet<String>();
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: then avoiding exception is not solution, should try by providing complete path of file

Comment: Also, post the complete class, or we can't "derive" the error you're getting. Catching exceptions is 99% of the time a sign of bad design/architecture, although I think this case is not at that level.

Comment: I apologize, I just edited the post

Comment: @user10947891 it's still incomplete. I mean, you just get a File, but you do nothing with it

Comment: ohhh I see. I guess I was trying to ask if the syntax for doing try and catch is correct in class, and then I ll add onto the method

Comment: Your code will never throw `FileNotFoundException`, hence the compiler error.

Comment: The problem here is that by simply instantating a new File, there are no exception thrown. The compiler is telling you that.

Comment: @Tom ahh I see. should I throw FileNotFoundException in my method when I write my code?

Comment: @user10947891 no. The error would remain. You just need to get rid of the catch block.

Comment: @LppEdd, getting rid of the catch block, meaning deleting it?

Comment: @user10947891 yes.

Comment: @LppEdd but I was given the assignment to use try catch instead of throws FileNotFoundException, how should I approach this?

Comment: You _could_ continue to write your actual code. You want to read a file, so do that.

Comment: However the File class never throws a FileNotFoundException as the more generic IOException is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not throw FileNotFoundException as you are not using the File object. However assuming you are going to read the file, if you add the following line of code after the File object is instantiated, your compiler will not complain.

```
public CaesarCipher()  {
    try {
        File dict = new File("dictionary/google10000.txt");
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(dict);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File does not exist, please try again: ");
    }
}
```

Of course, it depends on what you want to do with the file object.